# verify scrapy project code

Tags: python, scrapy

I try to extract job offers informations from this website and this is my code

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains =["tanitjobs.com/"]
    start_urls =["http://tanitjobs.com/search-results-jobs/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="offre"]/div[@class="detail"]')
        items = []
        item = DmozItem()
        for site in sites:
            item['title'] = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = site.xpath('div[@class="descriptionjob"]/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

but the result is incorrect (empty item list):

```
    {'desc': [],
     'link': [u'lien'],
     'title': []}
```

and many blocks like this ...

Comment: spider runs fine with me, expect for `site.xpath('div[@class="descriptionjob"]/text()')` where I suggest you use `site.xpath('.//div[@class="descriptionjob"]/text()')`

Comment: in my case it return the same item,  send me the code to verify plz ; abdaabdelfateh@gmail.com

Comment: I missed it the first time (I was simply printing the item in my test). The problem is with the item instantiation, which should be done in the loop

Comment: I also used `item['title'] = u''.join(site.xpath('a//text()').extract()).strip()` in my tests before, something @Talvalin also spotted by adding a `/strong`step in the XPath expression

Answer (score 2):

`item = DmozItem()` should be called for each loop iteration, otherwise you are rewriting the same item, appending the same item to the `items` list

It should look like:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains =["tanitjobs.com/"]
    start_urls =["http://tanitjobs.com/search-results-jobs/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="offre"]/div[@class="detail"]')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['desc'] = site.xpath('div[@class="descriptionjob"]/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: if I want that it return result from all pages (page1,page2,....)  how can I do it ; as you can verify it return that (crawled page =0)

Comment: Have a read of the CrawlSpider documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider

Answer (score 0):

Your title xpath didn't take into account the `<strong>` tags on either side of the text, and your desc xpath needs to go down another div to retrieve the required information.

I just noticed that the xpath for job description varies. The xpath in the code below returns job descriptions for the first three results but not subsequent ones. You would need to examine subsequent results to determine how the xpath changes to retrieve descriptions for those jobs.

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="offre"]/div[@class="detail"]')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title'] = site.xpath('normalize-space(a/strong/text())').extract()
        item['link'] = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        item['desc'] = site.xpath('normalize-space(./div/div[@class="descriptionjob"]/text())').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```